# How to send monitor data packets over the network for graphing?

Tags: linux, networking

I need to remotely monitor an embedded Linux system for system metrics like CPU/memory/disk as well as customized metrics. Not just the realtime data but also historical data.

Something like `netdata` would be ideal. However, the system is running an very old kernel which means it's very hard to port netdata to it.

I also checked the collectd. It doesn't support visualization out of box. It's writing data to a local file which has performance issues.

I am wondering whether there is a simple way to do just the data collection on the device and broadcast the data to the network? Then the heavy lift of data storage and visualization can be done on the PC side.

Comment: What stops you from using SSH and running netstat in there?

Comment: Are netstat and collectd really "too modern"? They seem like they're far _older_ than many other popular monitoring tools.

Comment: @user1686: I meant to say `netdata` instead of `netstat`, which is newer and has so many dependencies that it's hard to port over. `collectd` could be older, but still seems not easy to port, and doesn't support remote visualization easily.

Comment: @EugenRieck: I meant to write `netdata` instead of `netstat`. Regarding SSH, as far as I am aware of, SSH'ing into the box allows seeing real time data but not a historical graph of data. Using `tcpdump` etc saves the data but doesn't solve the visualization problem, also it's just network data and not scalable to other types of data. In addition, I intend this remote visualization to have a "dashboard" like UI that's usable for engineers and non-engineers alike.

Comment: @PengheGeng SSHing into the box allows you everything, that the local shell allows, plus port forwarding. So you can e.g. use collectd on a file in tmpfs and use SSH to move that file to the server on a short schedule.